# Send Email in Android development can't work

Tags: android, email

i was trying Send a Email in android development, when the program starts there is no incoming email

this is my code

```
public void NoticationEmail() {

    SenderEmail = "xxx@gmail.com";
    Subject = "Announcement";
    Message = "Test Email";

    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{SenderEmail});
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Subject);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Message);
    email.setType("message/rfc822");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose Email client :"));
    Intent pindah = new Intent(verification.this, AdminActivity.class);
    startActivity(pindah);
}
```

please help me

Comment: this code won't send email. It will open the chooser to select email client to send your email.

Comment: oh my god maybe @VladyslavMatviienko you have a reference about solution it

Comment: this is the common way to send email in Android apps, which allows users to send emails, and enables them to edit the email destination, subject, body, etc. It differs depending on what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your email replace of " email"|.You can use this code on-click of button. Then you will find the solution

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:" + email);
Intent myActivity2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
myActivity2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
startActivity(myActivity2);
```

Comment: Just add to your email  replace of " email"|.You can use this code on-click of button. Then you will find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below method to send email via mailing app

```
public void composeEmail(String[] addresses, String subject) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```